# Blogger B:if for comments and b:loop tag for displaying commnets

Tags: html, css, blogger

i have a blog on blogger: Mobtakr
I wanted to display comments in posts using the blogger tag b:loop instead of this data code

```
  <data:post.commentHtml/>
```

So i used this code cause i wanted to implement schema markup for comments : 
​

```
  <ol id="top-ra" >
<b:loop values='data:post.comments' var='comment'>
  <li itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/Comment'  class="comment" expr:id='data:comment.anchorName' >
<div class="comment-block">
<div class="comment-header">
<b:if cond='data:comment.authorUrl'>
<a expr:href='data:comment.authorUrl' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/Person' rel='nofollow'>
<span itemprop="name">
<data:comment.author/>
  </span>
</a>
<b:else/>
<a expr:href='data:comment.authorUrl' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/Person' rel='nofollow'>
<data:comment.author/></a>
</b:if>
<time expr:datetime="data:comment.timestamp" itemprop="dateCreated"  class="datetime secondary-text">
<data:comment.timestamp/>
  </time>
  </div>
<p  class='comment-body' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + data:comment.cmtBodyIdPostfix' itemprop='text'>
<data:comment.body/>
</p>
    </div> 
<div class="comment-replies" > 
<ol >

<b:loop values='data:post.comments-replies' var='comment'>
/*
So i want to loop the replies here and add some custom styles to them */ 
</b:loop> 
</ol>
    </div> 
</li>
</b:loop>
</ol>
```

the problem is i cant find a condition for comment replies or if the comment has replies then loop its replies with some style to make the replies different from the comment itself and margin the replies.

So, can anyone help me  ?

Is there a b:if tag with the condition cond="hasReplies" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is two versions of comments structure in Blogger, `Comments` and `threadedComments`.
The first one (which you are using) is customizable but unfortunately it does not support comment replies.

So if you want to use comment replies in your blog you should use the second one `threadedComments`, but it is not customizable, which means you can not edit HTML or add schema markup to it.

Comment: Thanks! i know that there are two versions and i checked blogger help and i found that they don't support comment  replies.
[link](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en)